# OIM 11gR2 PS3 AS400: Not able to pass connection to server job.

Tags: ibm-midrange, oim

during the past 3 weeks I am  facing a serious problem with the OIM AS400 Connector. The connectivity was working fine, until one weekend the AS400 Admins changed the storage of the AS400 System. Since then nothing seems to function.  The error  is the following:

```
**org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.ConnectorException: com.ibm.as400.access.ServerStartupException: Not able to pass connection to server job.  Subsystem problem detected.**

        at org.identityconnectors.framework.common.exceptions.ConnectorException.wrap(ConnectorException.java:101)

        at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400EntryIterator.<init>(AS400EntryIterator.java:45)

        at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400Connector.executeQuery(AS400Connector.java:565)

        at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400Connector.executeQuery(AS400Connector.java:163)

        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.SearchImpl.rawSearch(SearchImpl.java:105)

        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.SearchImpl.search(SearchImpl.java:82)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

        at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:93)

        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy506.search(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Ι tried using the JPing tool in jt400.jar utilities, and showed that the connection was working fine.
Ι produced more logs by configuring the jt400.properties file .I received the following:

```
**Exchange of random seeds failed with return code:

00 04 00 05                                      | ....             | ....             |

java.lang.Throwable**

    at com.ibm.as400.access.Trace.log(Trace.java:1164)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.Trace.log(Trace.java:1092)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getConnection(AS400ImplRemote.java:1147)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.openOffThread(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:360)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.getJobInfo(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:81)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall.getServerJob(ProgramCall.java:521)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall.run(ProgramCall.java:757)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserList.load(UserList.java:514)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserList.getUsers(UserList.java:378)

    at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400EntryIterator.<init>(AS400EntryIterator.java:43)

    at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400Connector.executeQuery(AS400Connector.java:565)

    at org.identityconnectors.as400.AS400Connector.executeQuery(AS400Connector.java:163)

    at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.SearchImpl.rawSearch(SearchImpl.java:105)

    at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.SearchImpl.search(SearchImpl.java:82)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.invoke(ConnectorAPIOperationRunnerProxy.java:93)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy532.search(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.local.operations.ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.invoke(ThreadClassLoaderManagerProxy.java:107)

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy532.search(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

    at org.identityconnectors.framework.impl.api.BufferedResultsProxy$BufferedResultsHandler.run(BufferedResultsProxy.java:162)

  **Establishing connection failed:

com.ibm.as400.access.ServerStartupException: Not able to pass connection to server job.  Subsystem problem detected.**

    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.returnSecurityException(AS400ImplRemote.java:1974)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getConnection(AS400ImplRemote.java:1148)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.openOffThread(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:360)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.getJobInfo(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:81)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall.getServerJob(ProgramCall.java:521)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall.run(ProgramCall.java:757)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserList.load(UserList.java:514)

    at com.ibm.as400.access.UserList.getUsers(UserList.java:378)
```

We do not know what seems to be the problem. We have contacted the AS400 Admins and they cannot figure it out as well.
Has anyone experienced anything similar before, or does anyone have any insights on this?

Comment: Not sure but may be connection issue. can you restart connector server if you are using one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance routing your QZDASOINIT or QZSCSRVS or QZRCSRVS jobs to a different subsystem? If yes, is the said subsystem active? I got a very similar error in my app server logs:

*Caused by: com.xxxx.xxx.framework.common.utilities.UXException: Cannot create unit for user on system due to error [GUI administrator password might have been changed since the last login.  Signoff from the system and contact the GUI administrator - Not able to pass connection to server job.  Subsystem problem detected.]*

and was able to fix it by removing the specific client subsystem defined for the database server.